# Samba file shares - how to get all the files that changed since a given time in the fastest way possible?

Tags: samba

I have a huge list of samba shares that are in format like

```
\\10.1.5.3\Share1
\\10.1.5.3\Share2
\\10.1.5.4\Share3
\\10.1.5.3\Share4
... thousands more of these ...
```

I have indexed these folders' content by walking the file tree for each folder. Takes a really long time but no problems.

Now I want to incrementally re-index these folders periodically if the file has changed since first index. So naturally I once again walk the file tree for each samba share directory using time stamps to know if the file has changed since I last indexed.

It's taking a long time because of the number of folders/files whose timestamps to visit in the folders is so large. Is there a faster way to do this? What techniques do people use?

Answer (score 1):

Theoretically, the `smb` protocol supports a features called 'changing notification'. It basically issues a real-time notification when a file changes.

However, I can not comment on its reliability, so you mileage may vary.